# What is the best way to create this div?

Tags: css

[this is the div i want to create](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/1264/box2ri.jpg)

in this case i have white background outside and i want to give little bit inner shadow effect on my div(liquid) and rounded corner also. i usually create 10 divs warp, content, 4x bar, 4x corner with 6 img, when i creat rouned corner divs in this way i have to create 10 divs and long css for 1 box i want to get rid off this. can anyone help me with some css and short code to creat that div.

Comment: What are the limitations of the expected div? Constant size or variable? Always on a white background on the outside? What about the inside?

Comment: You can use something like this to generate the effect you are looking for: http://www.css3.me/

Answer (score 2):

```
.box {
width: 250px;
height: 300px;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px #333;
}

<div class='box'></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QmkNE/

That should - roughly - represent what you asked for. Mind you, you need to cover some cross-browser css stuff for the border-radius and box-shadow to work consistently.

Comment: +1: If OP can stick with css3/html5 then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use CSS3 to create a stylish div with color background having opacity.